# SoapAPI call to python dict process produces empty file

Tags: python, python-2.7, soap

I have a working Python script to pull a single variable from csv file replaces a single value in the script {0}, it then runs a soapAPI call, I then want to collect soap Response output two values from the Soap response into a CSV file.

Here is a typical Soap Response after running my script..

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0" xmlns:ns3="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/auditmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns4="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/configurationmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns5="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicediagnostics/v1_0" xmlns:ns6="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns7="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/groupmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns8="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/subscribermgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns9="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/workflowmgmt/v1_0">
         <ns6:parameterValue>
            <ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.UpTime</ns2:name>
            <ns2:value>3414</ns2:value>
         </ns6:parameterValue>
      </ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I want both the folowing values to appear in the csv
name  --> InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.UpTime (column A)
value --> 3414 (column B)

I believe I am having an issue with the convert xml to python dict process (just can't figure it out)

I end up with a generated csv file but with no data other than
[image of generated csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4p97.png)

Here's the working Python SoapAPI Script

```
 #!/usr/bin/env python

import requests
import csv
import getopt
import sys
import time
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import xmltodict

from lxml import objectify

xml_string = """<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0" xmlns:ns3="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/auditmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns4="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/configurationmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns5="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicediagnostics/v1_0" xmlns:ns6="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns7="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/groupmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns8="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/subscribermgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns9="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/workflowmgmt/v1_0"><ns6:parameterValue><ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary</ns2:name><ns2:value>InternetGatewayDevice:1.4[](Baseline:1,Time:1,IPPing:1,CaptivePortal:1,TraceRoute:1,EthernetLAN:1,WiFiLAN:1,DeviceAssociation:2),VoiceService:1.0[1](Baseline:1)</ns2:value></ns6:parameterValue></ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""
xml_object = objectify.fromstring(xml_string)
print xml_object.__dict__

def read_run(url, csv_file):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(open(csv_file))
    for row in csv_reader:
        print row
        if len(row) == 1:
            serial_number = row[0]
            GetParameterValues_element(url, serial_number)
        elif len(row) == 1:
            print ' [serial_number] format provided, associate element with specified subscriber'
            serial_number = row[0]
            GetParameterValues_element(url, serial_number)
        else:
            print 'Invalid csv file provided'
            print 'Only support below format'
            print 'serial_number'
            sys.exit(0)
    print 'Complete All GPV.'


def GetParameterValues_element(url, serial_number):
    request = u"""<soapenv:Envelope
        xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
        xmlns:v1="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0"
        xmlns:v11="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0"
        xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
       <soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security>
        <wsse:UsernameToken>
           <wsse:Username>unHERE</wsse:Username>
           <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">pwHERE</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
     </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
     <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:GetDeviceParameterValuesRequest>
         <v1:deviceSelector xsi:type="v11:SerialNumberAndOUIDeviceSelector" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <v11:serialNumber>184795206106368</v11:serialNumber>
            <v11:oui>0000C5</v11:oui>
         </v1:deviceSelector>
         <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
         <v1:parameterName>{0}</v1:parameterName>
         <v1:timeout>
            <v11:value>5</v11:value>
            <v11:units>MINUTES</v11:units>
         </v1:timeout>
      </v1:GetDeviceParameterValuesRequest>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>""".format(serial_number)
    soap_request(url, request)


def soap_request(url, request):
    encoded_request = request.encode('utf-8')
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
    response = requests.post(url=url, headers=headers, data=encoded_request, verify=False)
    #print response.content
    print response.content
    write_csv(response.content)
    
def write_csv(data):
    field_names = ["name"]
    with open("testoutput.csv", "w") as f:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(f, field_names)
    
        collected_items = [
          {
              "name": "value",
         },
        ]
    
        # Write a header row
        writer.writerow({x: x for x in field_names})
    
        for item_property_dict in collected_items:
            writer.writerow(item_property_dict)
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], 'hu:f:', ['url=', 'file=', 'help'])

    sample_file = 'sample.csv'
    soap_url = 'http://poc5.servername.online/dmc-nbiws/'
    for k, v in opts:
        if k in ['-h', '--help']:
            print 'Usage :'
            print '-h or --help\t Display script usage'
            print '-u or --url\t The URL of Soap request, if it is not provided, using szeco142 by default'
            print """-f or --file\t Sample data file, must be a csv file,
                  if it is not provided, using /opt/sample.csv by default"""
            sys.exit(0)

        if k in ['-u', '--url']:
            soap_url = v

        if k in ['-f', '--file']:
            sample_file = v

    print soap_url
    print sample_file
    read_run(soap_url, sample_file)
```

```html
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0" xmlns:ns3="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/auditmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns4="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/configurationmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns5="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicediagnostics/v1_0" xmlns:ns6="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns7="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/groupmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns8="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/subscribermgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns9="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/workflowmgmt/v1_0">
         <ns6:parameterValue>
            <ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.UpTime</ns2:name>
            <ns2:value>76689</ns2:value>
         </ns6:parameterValue>
         <ns6:parameterValue>
            <ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.MemoryStatus.Total</ns2:name>
            <ns2:value>484420</ns2:value>
         </ns6:parameterValue>
         <ns6:parameterValue>
            <ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceInfo.FirstUseDate</ns2:name>
            <ns2:value>1970-01-01T00:09:43Z</ns2:value>
         </ns6:parameterValue>
      </ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

When I run the following through pprint I get the following error "Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./test_soap.py", line 27, in 
pprint(xml_object['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse']['ns6:parameterValue']['ns2:name'])
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

because I have multiple parameters parameter returns with the same tags ns2 and ns6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FekSq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to pars your xml_string in your example using the below, also gave an example of parsing out an example of the end data you need;

```
import xmltodict
from pprint import pprint

    xml_string = """<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><SOAP-ENV:Header/><SOAP-ENV:Body><ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse xmlns:ns2="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0" xmlns:ns3="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/auditmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns4="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/configurationmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns5="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicediagnostics/v1_0" xmlns:ns6="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns7="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/groupmgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns8="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/subscribermgmt/v1_0" xmlns:ns9="http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/workflowmgmt/v1_0"><ns6:parameterValue><ns2:name>InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary</ns2:name><ns2:value>InternetGatewayDevice:1.4[](Baseline:1,Time:1,IPPing:1,CaptivePortal:1,TraceRoute:1,EthernetLAN:1,WiFiLAN:1,DeviceAssociation:2),VoiceService:1.0[1](Baseline:1)</ns2:value></ns6:parameterValue></ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>"""
xml_object = xmltodict.parse(xml_string)
pprint(xml_object)
pprint(xml_object['SOAP-ENV:Envelope']['SOAP-ENV:Body']['ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse']['ns6:parameterValue']['ns2:name'])
```

output of this for me is;

```
OrderedDict([('SOAP-ENV:Envelope',
              OrderedDict([('@xmlns:SOAP-ENV',
                            'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'),
                           ('SOAP-ENV:Header', None),
                           ('SOAP-ENV:Body',
                            OrderedDict([('ns6:GetDeviceParameterValuesResponse',
                                          OrderedDict([('@xmlns:ns2',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/base/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns3',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/auditmgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns4',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/configurationmgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns5',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicediagnostics/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns6',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/devicemgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns7',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/groupmgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns8',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/subscribermgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('@xmlns:ns9',
                                                        'http://twowire.com/dmc/apps/nbiws/workflowmgmt/v1_0'),
                                                       ('ns6:parameterValue',
                                                        OrderedDict([('ns2:name',
                                                                      'InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary'),
                                                                     ('ns2:value',
                                                                      'InternetGatewayDevice:1.4[](Baseline:1,Time:1,IPPing:1,CaptivePortal:1,TraceRoute:1,EthernetLAN:1,WiFiLAN:1,DeviceAssociation:2),VoiceService:1.0[1](Baseline:1)')]))]))]))]))])


'InternetGatewayDevice.DeviceSummary'
```

Comment: Thank you so much. ! you really have helped me move this forward I was able to replicate your result. I have one further question, in the example, I provided it only returned one parameter but in the real world it will have multiple parameter rtrn with the same nameSpace.. exmaple.

Comment: Sorry, just got the email about your comment.
So if there are multiple results returned from the single json key then they should be returned as a python list.
So you can work with them in that format.
If you give me a direct example then I can give you a better answer.